# how can I a calculate the force of attraction between hemispere and a mass

Tags: integration

how can I calculate the force of attraction between a uniform solid hemisphere of radius **a** and a mass m located on the axis of the sphre and at  a distance **a** outside the hemisphere

Comment: See https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-a-triple-integrals/session-78-applications-gravitational-attraction/gravity-and-a-half-sphere/. Warning: in this example the density isn't constant.